# What does $\partial_p$ mean?

Tags: notation

In the Wikipedia article on [ridge detection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ridge_detection), there is this symbol $\partial_p$.

I know that $\frac{\partial f}{\partial p}$ is sometimes denoted as $\partial_p f$, but I've never seen $\partial_p$ written alone before.

Comment: Most likely they mean the differentation operator $\frac{\partial}{\partial p}$.

Comment: probably be they choose $p$ to take either the symbolic value $x$ or $y$

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_derivative#Notation might help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The notation
$$
\partial_p = \sin \beta \partial_x - \cos \beta \partial_y \\
\partial_q = \cos \beta \partial_x + \sin \beta \partial_y
$$
means this is true applied to any suitable function $f$, e.g.
$$
\partial_p f = \sin \beta \partial_x f - \cos \beta \partial_y f\\
\partial_q f = \cos \beta \partial_x f + \sin \beta \partial_y f
$$
or alternatively, if you like,
$$
f_p = \sin \beta f_x - \cos \beta f_y \\
f_q = \cos \beta f_x + \sin \beta f_y
$$

Answer (score 0):

$\partial_p$ is just that, the differential operator. It is written alone sometimes to emphasize it's own properties as a map, without needing a specific function to act on. In the article they discuss the properties of differentiating in a rotated frame. This changes the differential operator itself in those coordinates. So it makes sense to write it all out.